# How to show how many times a country appears in my database after displaying with distinct all countries?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$countryQuery = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `country` FROM `general` ORDER BY `country` ASC");
$countryNumRows = mysql_num_rows($countryQuery);

echo '<h3>Countries: '.$countryNumRows.'</h3>';


while($country = mysql_fetch_array($countryQuery)) {
echo $country[country].'<br>';
}
```

This gives me an output like

```
Countries: 55

AL
AR
AT
AU
BE
BG
BH
BR
CA
...
...
...
```

My question is what can I edit or add to my existing code so that I get the number of how many times a country appears in my database?

for example

```
AL (13)
AR (4)
AT (49)
AU (36)
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `group by` clause to apply an aggregate function, like `count` per each group:

```
SELECT   country, COUNT(*) 
FROM     general
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 0):

Use count and aggregate the data grouping by the state name:

```
SELECT 
  `country`,
  COUNT(`country`) as country_count
FROM `general` 
GROUP BY `country`
ORDER BY `country` ASC
```

As side note `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, look at `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by`, like this:

```
SELECT `country`, COUNT(*) FROM `general` GROUP BY `country` ORDER BY `country` ASC
```